# getting duplicate paths in my vscode integrated terminal

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, zsh

I have written a code where I am looking for a environment variable called `SQLCONFIGPATH` in my computer.  Then reading a `config.ini` file.

I went to `.zprofile` and the path variable.  When I call the file from my integrated shell, I get the following error:

```
 /Users/Me/Documents/research/Home/python/my-lab/sql_config/Users/Me/Documents/research/Home/python/my-lab/sql_config/config.ini
```

But when I go to my regular shell (not in my vscode), I `cd` into the directory where the file is located and am able to call the file with no issues.
How do I call this within vscode's integrated shell? It seems there is a duplicate being created here.  Also when I go into vscode's coderunner and run the file, it runs with no issues.

The code is supposed to read this path:

```
Users/Me/Documents/research/Home/python/my-lab/sql_config/config.ini
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could fiddle with your .zshrc and .zprofile to ensure that a directory is not added redundantly to your PATH. A much easier approach would be to use a

```
typeset -aU path
```

This would ensure that zsh itself keeps duplicates out from PATH.